power flow automation communication between webapp and powerbi
I try to set up a connection to a webapplication. The webapplication has a login screen

After the user enters a username and password it gets redirected to new page where select a application link and gets redirected to its default page.
I am trying to build power automation workflow that will provide access this form provide username and password so it gets authenticated by the web-app navigates to a certain page and downlads a file that will push to powerbi.
I started a data>>Custom connector. below it is its definition
    swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: PrkYrdApp
  description: Connection to Yardi one centralised application
  version: '1.0'
host: primekapital.yardione.com
basePath: /
schemes:
  - https
consumes:
  - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
produces: []
paths:
  /Account/Login:
    post:
      summary: LogIn
      description: Use YardiOne Login page username and password
      operationId: Yrd1LoginCredentials
      parameters:
        - name: Content-Type
          in: header
          required: true
          type: string
          default: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              AppReturnUrl:
                type: string
                description: AppReturnUrl
              Username:
                type: string
                description: Username
                example: office
              Password:
                type: string
                description: Password
                example: samplepwd undisclosed
              __RequestVerificationToken:
                type: string
                description: __RequestVerificationToken
                default:
                  CfDJ8OSS7LnBRTdHi6cpNh6B26PYnal_LN4kM-0vISf4sHuCTd5dV1PBSm5myNCMlcnawORq6pzU_i2B62AEFBEpxeELdDwFOQ3tjvpcJ7UHl6w4s1xHgdTVCpMvwt5xRqqQ03lrLMS7LI_JCck6TNGLYTA
              button:
                type: string
                description: button
                example: login
      responses:
        default:
          description: default
          schema: {}
definitions: {}
parameters: {}
responses: {}
securityDefinitions: {}
security: []
tags: []

The connection to the webapplication through the login page ends in an error.
What is wrong?
